# extjs 4.2 how to create a queryplan

Tags: extjs, extjs4

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox
has a beforeQuery event. But when I try this I get a complaint that there is no queryplan.

How can this be established? I can find no documentation anywhere in how to set up a queryplan.

```
                                {
                                    xtype: 'combo',
                                    flex: 2,
                                    fieldLabel: 'other',
                                    displayField: 'city_name',
                                    name: 'city_name',
                                    itemId:'city_name',
                                    emptyText: 'plaats',
                                    store:{
                                        type: 'location.city'
                                    },

                                   beforeQuery: function( queryEvent, eOpts ){
                                        var me = this;

                                        var store = me.getStore();

                                        store.proxy.extraParams={
                                            fieldName: 'city.name',
                                            fieldValue: me.getValue()
                                        };

                                        // return true;
                                    }, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**In short:**

You are overriding the beforeQuery **method** instead of listening for the beforeQuery **event**.
Listen for the `beforequery` event in the controller or add a listener to the object like this:

```
listeners: {
    beforequery: function( queryPlan, eOpts){
        var me = this,
            store = me.getStore();

        store.proxy.extraParams={
            fieldName: 'city.name',
            fieldValue: me.getValue()
        };
        return true; //optional only false would cancel the event see beforQuery method
    }
}
```

**The longer version:**

The `doQuery` method looks like this:

```
doQuery: function(queryString, forceAll, rawQuery) {
    var me = this,

    // Decide if, and how we are going to query the store
        queryPlan = me.beforeQuery({
            query: queryString || '',
            rawQuery: rawQuery,
            forceAll: forceAll,
            combo: me,
            cancel: false
        });

    ...some other code where the queryPlan is needed...

        return true;
},
```

You are overriding the beforeQuery method and returning nothing (or true/false) instead of listening for the event!

This is what the beforeQuery method looks like:

```
beforeQuery: function(queryPlan) {
    var me = this;

    // Allow beforequery event to veto by returning false
    if (me.fireEvent('beforequery', queryPlan) === false) {
        queryPlan.cancel = true;
    }

    // Allow beforequery event to veto by returning setting the cancel flag
    else if (!queryPlan.cancel) {

        // If the minChars threshold has not been met, and we're not forcing an "all" query, cancel the query
        if (queryPlan.query.length < me.minChars && !queryPlan.forceAll) {
            queryPlan.cancel = true;
        }
    }
    return queryPlan;
}
```

If you intentionally override the beforeQuery method => return the queryPlan else use the event instead. As you can see, using the event you can also cancel the query by returning false in the event handler of the beforeQuery.